# UIImage view losing images while navigating back

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Look at this GIF of image view loses images while navigating back:

[image: image view loses images while navigating back]

I fill in detailsVC and press next to upload images. As i upload images and press Back button on navigation bar and then again press next to arrive at this view controller, images previously selected are removed.

I want that images selected should stay there regardless of navigation. View controller should sustain those images on imageviews.

Comment: are you saved image any where in your code can you show some code what you had try out

Comment: You have to maintain array of images that are being selected from the image picker in the first view controller and pass the reference to detailVC. Then when image is picked you should add it to the array and when it is removed you should remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you storing the images in detailVC? The reason why the images are cleared is that the reference of your VC has been removed, thus the variables where you are storing. If it is array make it static and it will remain until the app is alive.

Comment: I am not storing images in detailVC. My sequence is like:                  detailsVC -> ImagesVC. I choose and upload images in ImagesVC and then display them on image views. Once i go back to detailsVC and press next, images are gone.                                                                                            detailsVC (fill details) -> ImagesVC (upload Images)

going back, say to fix some information previously entered wrong;

       detailsVC   <-  imagesVC

and then coming back to imagesVC, images are gone.

Comment: I see, when navigating back from imagesVC to detailsVC the reference of imageVC is removed, so the images as well. If you do not store the reference of images somewhere you will loose them. When you choose the images in imagesVC try to store them in static array. And every time you visit imagesVC try to load images from this array first. If it is empty  you do nothing.

Comment: okay thanks Buka i will do that. What i want is that my imagesVC does not load images everytime view controller is shown. It only loads those images selected by the user. So i think i need to empty that array. But when? in viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear?

Comment: You will have only selected images in this static array. It depends on the logic, you can free the array when the form is submitted by `imagesVC.myStaticArray = []` from anywhere you need. If you free it in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear you will not manage to load them in imagesVC ;)